# Area appears in click-based input Angular Material components when custom theme applied

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Since I applied a custom theme to my project, whenever I click on a button, checkbox or chip among others, a weird grey area appears just like I show in the gif.
[image]

I managed to fix the buttons by setting `--mat-mdc-button-ripple-color: none` but I don't know if is the correct approach and I don't know how to solve it with the rest of the components either because it doesn't seem to be a property like that on them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was that I didn't add `@include mat.core` when I applied my theme to the components. It's all working now.